# Mongoose populate an array field with another Model object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am really confused on how to approach this problem. I want to populate my studyGroups array of my *User* model with a specific *StudyGroup* model. I obtain the specific user and studyGroup through the router (`cuid: req.params.cuid` for the users, and `guid: req.params.guid` for the studyGroup).

Here is what my code looks like:

*User*

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  cuid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  firstName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  lastName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  studentId: { type: 'Number', required: true },
  password: { type: 'String', required: true },
  email: { type: 'String', required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
  lastLogin: { type: 'Date', default: null, required: false },
  studyGroups: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "studyGroup"
      }
    ]
});
```

*StudyGroup*

```
const studyGroupSchema = new Schema({
  guid: { type: 'String', required: true },
  groupName: { type: 'String', required: true },
  course: { type: 'String', required: true },
  teacher: { type: 'String', required: true },
  description: { type: 'String', required: true },
  dateAdded: { type: 'Date', default: Date.now, required: true },
});
```

*Route*

`router.route('/:cuid/studyGroups/:guid').post(UserController.addUserStudyGroups);`

Here is where all the action happens. First I find the user, and now I want to add the whole studyGroup model object to the array. So my thought was to query the *studyGroup* using the `guid: req.params.guid` but don't know if that is the proper way.

*Controller*

```
export function addUserStudyGroups(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ cuid: req.params.cuid }).populate('studyGroups').exec((err, studyGroups) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    study
    return res.json({ studyGroups });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can now do it in Mongo 3.2 using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

`$lookup` takes four arguments

`from`:     Specifies the collection in the same database to perform the join with. The from collection cannot be sharded.

`localField`: Specifies the field from the documents input to the $lookup stage. $lookup performs an equality match on the localField to the foreignField from the documents of the from collection.

`foreignField`: Specifies the field from the documents in the from collection.

`as`: Specifies the name of the new array field to add to the input documents. The new array field contains the matching documents from the from collection.

```
db.User.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$bars"},
  {$lookup: {
    from:"studyGroups",
    localField: "studyGroups",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "studyGroupList"

   }}
)
```